# How to remote desktop without showing authentication window in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-desktop

I've tried remote desktop (win server 2010) via this batch code in Windows 8 and it works without showing authentication window:

```
cmdkey /generic:"192.168.1.3" /user:"User112" /pass:"Password"
mstsc /v:"192.168.1.3"
```

But when I've tried it in Windows 7, it shows me authentication window and needs password.

How to remote desktop without showing authentication window in Windows  7?

Answer (score 2):

When you get the Remote Desktop dialog authentication windows is displayed, click on 'Show Options'. The General Tab allows you to enter a username and save the configuration as an RDP file. Make sure 'Always Ask for Credentials' is unchecked and Connect then save this configuration. Not exactly a batch file but clicking on the RDP file in the future will open the desktop connection without having to enter your credentials.

Comment: I've tried it, but it shows me windows security(authentication) again.

Comment: Check your group policy on the client machine. The group policy settings under:

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client
on the client machine need to be configured with:

Do not allow passwords to be saved: *Not Configured*    and     
Prompt for credentials on the client computer: *Not Configured*

Comment: Both of them were "Not Configured", but it again shows authentication form and needs password.